# blue noise error distribution in (MC)MC estimation

Tags: sampling, references, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, noise

In computer graphics, you have an (MC)MC estimate $Q_i$ of the color value of the $i$th pixel and a true value $I_i$. Now you take $\epsilon_i:=Q_i-I_i$, which can be thought of as an "error image".

Now, one has found out, that if the Fourier transform (https://vincmazet.github.io/bip/filtering/fourier.html) of $\epsilon$ has a "blue noise profile" (almost no low frequency content), then the "visually perceived error" is reduced.

What my question here is: Is there any ongoing work in a more general or different (MC)MC context? I mean, from an abstract view point, the problem is that we have finite number of estimates $Q_1,\ldots,Q_k$ of integrals $I_1,\ldots,I_k$ and you can assume that the domains of the integrands are disjoint and their union is the whole space.